# cannot load such file -- script/rails : Getting this error while remote debugging through RubyMine

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, debugging, rubymine

I am getting following error while remote debugging through RubyMine IDE.

```
$ bundle exec rdebug-ide --port 1234 -- script/rails server
Fast Debugger (ruby-debug-ide 0.4.9) listens on :1234
    /home/amit/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p125/gems/ruby-debug-ide19-0.4.12/lib/ruby-debug-ide.rb:123:in `debug_load'
    /home/amit/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p125/gems/ruby-debug-ide19-0.4.12/lib/ruby-debug-ide.rb:123:in `debug_program'
    /home/amit/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p125/gems/ruby-debug-ide19-0.4.12/bin/rdebug-ide:87:in `<top (required)>'
    /home/amit/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p125/bin/rdebug-ide:19:in `load'
    /home/amit/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p125/bin/rdebug-ide:19:in `<main>'
Uncaught exception: cannot load such file -- script/rails
```

I followed [this link](http://rails.vandenabeele.com/blog/2011/12/21/installing-ruby-debug19-with-ruby-1-dot-9-3-on-rvm/) to install require gems for remote debug.

Here is Gemfile configuration for remote debug

```
#To Debug
  gem 'linecache19', '0.5.13', :path => "~/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p125/gems/linecache19-0.5.13/"
  gem 'ruby-debug-base19', '0.11.26', :path => "~/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p125/gems/ruby-debug-base19-0.11.26/"
  gem 'ruby-debug19', :require => 'ruby-debug'
  gem 'ruby-debug-ide19'
```

The application is running with **Ruby 1.9.3** and **Rails 3.0.11**.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

You are using some weird debug gems, only the following are needed:

- `ruby-debug-base19x`
- `ruby-debug-ide`

First, remove all the `ruby-debug*` gems, then install the required gems using the following commands:

```
gem install ruby-debug-base19x --pre
gem install ruby-debug-ide --pre
```

You should get the following (or newer) versions:

```
ruby-debug-base19x (0.11.30.pre10)
ruby-debug-ide (0.4.17.beta9)
```

Adjust your `Gemfile` to include only these **two** gems (except the app specific gems).

If you are getting `linecache19` related errors, install it as follows:

```
curl -OL http://rubyforge.org/frs/download.php/75414/linecache19-0.5.13.gem
gem install linecache19-0.5.13.gem
```

@Anjan has contributed the complete Gemfile changes for debugging:

```
gem 'linecache19', '>= 0.5.13', :git => 'https://github.com/robmathews/linecache19-0.5.13.git'
gem 'ruby-debug-base19x', '>= 0.11.30.pre10'
gem 'ruby-debug-ide', '>= 0.4.17.beta14'
```

Don't forget to **update** the bundle.

Comment: Thanks a lot @CrazyCoder. It worked like a charm. Without `linecache19-0.5.13.gem` I got `undefined symbol: ruby_current_thread - /home/amit/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p125@global/gems/linecache19-0.5.12/lib/trace_nums19.so (LoadError)` It is surprising as I had uninstalled `linecache19-0.5.12`. Anyway, I installed `linecache19-0.5.13.gem` by following your steps and error gone.

Comment: @CrayzyCode, RubyMine Event Log window prompt to install missing plugin. Should I install with above Gemfile configuration? However without installing I could not find any issue so far while debugging.

Comment: @AmitPatel, deleting `Gemfile.lock` and running `bundle install` should also help.

Comment: What does the --pre mean? I tried on any possible guide but I didn't find it

Comment: It means pre-release version (beta, preXX, etc).

Comment: This is what I used in my Gemfile to install the required gems through bundler: `gem 'linecache19', '>= 0.5.13', :git => 'https://github.com/robmathews/linecache19-0.5.13.git'; gem 'ruby-debug-base19x', '>= 0.11.30.pre10'; gem 'ruby-debug-ide', '>= 0.4.17.beta14'`

Answer (score 3):

I already resolved this issue with help of [@CrazyCoder](https://stackoverflow.com/users/104891/crazycoder) by following all instructions he mentioned [above](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10325110/517483) in his answer.

I am answering here just to account what worked for me so might be useful to community.

Here is final entry of my Gem file

```
gem 'linecache19', '0.5.13', :path => "~/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p125/gems/linecache19-0.5.13"
gem 'ruby-debug-base19x', '0.11.30.pre10'
gem 'ruby-debug-ide', '0.4.17.beta9'
```

Without `:path` for `linecache19` I was getting following error.

```
You have requested:
  linecache19 = 0.5.13

The bundle currently has linecache19 locked at 0.5.12.
Try running `bundle update linecache19`
```