# Unable to debug in RubyMine 4.5 using Ruby 1.9.3

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rubymine

My apologies for the length of the question, but I want to make it clear I am not making any stupid mistakes!

So, I am struggling to get debugging working in RubyMine 4.5 using Ruby 1.9.3, my steps are as follows:

Fresh (i.e. having removed all previous ruby and gem directories) install of Ruby 1.9.3, Ruby Gems, DevKit and Rails (following [this guide](http://thirdeye.ibtgames.com/2011/11/installing-ruby-on-rails-on-win7/)) - that works fine.

I then try to begin working with my team's ruby code. I open up the directory in RubyMine (remembering first to delete the `.idea` directory) and am prompted to run `bundle install` which I do (from console) as requested. This completes successfully. Restart RubyMine.

I then ensure Ruby is working: Tools > IRB Console > `puts "test"` `#test => nil` - Works
I now try the debugger (`SHIFT` + `F9`) and see the message:

`The gem ruby-debug-base19x required by the debugger is currently not installed. Would you like to install it?"`

I click cancel and check my Gemfile, the only ones related to debugging present are:

```
# Debugging
gem 'debugger'
#gem 'ruby-debug-base19', :require => false
#gem 'ruby-debug19', :require => false
gem 'ruby-prof', :require => false #, :git => 'git://github.com/wycats/ruby-prof.git'
```

Looks like we have debugger in favour of `ruby-debug`. Reading [here](http://devnet.jetbrains.net/message/5459214?tstart=0), however, it seems `debugger` is not sufficient. I need to install `ruby-debug-base19x`. So, following [SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10323119/cannot-load-such-file-script-rails-getting-this-error-while-remote-debuggin), I comment out debugger from Gemfile and run

```
gem install ruby-debug-base19x --pre
gem install ruby-debug-ide --pre
```

Which run fine, so I add

```
gem 'ruby-debug-base19x', '0.11.30.pre10'
gem 'ruby-debug-ide', '0.4.17.beta14'
```

to my Gemfile, and run a `bundle install` from the console.

Finally, i open the debugger inside RubyMine (SHIFT + F9). And `puts "test" #test => nil` works again. So i try double clicking in the gutter of my script to create a breakpoint, RubyMine pauses for a second and then i get:

```
D:\Ruby\Ruby193\bin\ruby.exe -e $stdout.sync=true;$stderr.sync=true;load($0=ARGV.shift) D:/Ruby/Ruby193/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/ruby-debug-ide-0.4.17.beta14/bin/rdebug-ide --dispatcher-port 55451 --port 55452 -- S:/code/account_groups/script/rails console
Fast Debugger (ruby-debug-ide 0.4.17.beta14, ruby-debug-base 0.11.30.pre10) listens on 127.0.0.1:55452
D:/Ruby/Ruby193/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/debugger-1.1.4/lib/ruby_debug.so: warning: already initialized constant VERSION
5992: Exception in DebugThread loop: undefined method `errmsg' for #<Debugger::ControlState:0x2a2f3e8>
Backtrace:
D:/Ruby/Ruby193/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/debugger-1.1.4/lib/ruby-debug/command.rb:160:in `errmsg'
  from: D:/Ruby/Ruby193/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/debugger-1.1.4/lib/ruby-debug/commands/breakpoints.rb:81:in `execute'
  from: D:/Ruby/Ruby193/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/ruby-debug-ide-0.4.17.beta14/lib/ruby-debug-ide/ide_processor.rb:89:in `block in process_commands'
  from: D:/Ruby/Ruby193/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/ruby-debug-ide-0.4.17.beta14/lib/ruby-debug-ide/ide_processor.rb:86:in `catch'
  from: D:/Ruby/Ruby193/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/ruby-debug-ide-0.4.17.beta14/lib/ruby-debug-ide/ide_processor.rb:86:in `process_commands'
  from: D:/Ruby/Ruby193/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/ruby-debug-ide-0.4.17.beta14/lib/ruby-debug-ide.rb:160:in `block in start_control'

Process finished with exit code 0
```

I have also tried using a backup copy of the code and following the same steps, i also get the following error when trying to load up the debugger:

```
Uncaught exception: cannot load such file -- ruby-debug
    D:/Ruby/Ruby193/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/activesupport-3.2.6/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:251:in `require'
    D:/Ruby/Ruby193/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/activesupport-3.2.6/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:251:in `block in require'
    D:/Ruby/Ruby193/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/activesupport-3.2.6/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:236:in `load_dependency'
    D:/Ruby/Ruby193/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/activesupport-3.2.6/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:251:in `require'
    S:/code/account_groups_so/lib/systematic-online/r_spec_runner.rb:5:in `<top (required)>'
    D:/Ruby/Ruby193/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/activesupport-3.2.6/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:251:in `require'
    D:/Ruby/Ruby193/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/activesupport-3.2.6/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:251:in `block in require'
    D:/Ruby/Ruby193/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/activesupport-3.2.6/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:236:in `load_dependency'
    D:/Ruby/Ruby193/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/activesupport-3.2.6/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:251:in `require'
    S:/code/account_groups_so/config/environment.rb:12:in `block in <top (required)>'
    S:/code/account_groups_so/config/environment.rb:12:in `each'
    S:/code/account_groups_so/config/environment.rb:12:in `<top (required)>'
    D:/Ruby/Ruby193/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/activesupport-3.2.6/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:251:in `require'
    D:/Ruby/Ruby193/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/activesupport-3.2.6/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:251:in `block in require'
    D:/Ruby/Ruby193/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/activesupport-3.2.6/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:236:in `load_dependency'
    D:/Ruby/Ruby193/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/activesupport-3.2.6/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:251:in `require'
    D:/Ruby/Ruby193/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/railties-3.2.6/lib/rails/application.rb:103:in `require_environment!'
    D:/Ruby/Ruby193/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/railties-3.2.6/lib/rails/commands.rb:40:in `<top (required)>'
    S:/code/account_groups_so/script/rails:6:in `require'
    S:/code/account_groups_so/script/rails:6:in `<top (required)>'
```

There is nothing wrong with the script (i have used it fine before) and the trace seems related to `ruby-debug-ide` - what's going on?

Thanks for any help - this is driving me mad!

Comment: Please provide a small sample project to reproduce this issue.

Comment: Thanks for the response, but I'm not sure what you want me to provide? I can give you my full Gemfile, Gemfile.lock or print out my Ruby ENV?

Comment: Zip and share the directory with the sample script, RubyMine project (`.idea` directory) which will show where breakpoint is set, `Gemfile`, `Gemfile.lock`.

Comment: I am reluctant to upload my script as it is IP of my company (and it is not the issue). I have updated and expanded by my question with new symptoms as I have somehow overcome the previous error and now am back to an error I had before (i have re-installed numerous times today!) Does that help?

Comment: Do you mean that the bug is specific to this particular script that you can's share and there is no way you can reproduce this problem with any other script?

Comment: No. It is in no way specific to the script. This happens with any .rb file on my installation of RubyMine. I believe the issue is incompatible debug gems. I will do another fresh install and attempt to rephrase the question (I have seen so many errors, I am not sure which to include - hence the confusion above).

Comment: You can prepare and share a dummy project with similar configuration and any script that is not protected by your IP.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/14475/discussion-between-ryan-and-crazycoder)

Answer (score 18, accepted):

**UPDATE**: RubyMine 6+ supports debugger gem.

Make sure to remove `gem 'debugger'` from your `Gemfile`, it's a known conflict that will break debugging from RubyMine. You need only 2 gems related to debugger, exactly as stated in my [another answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10325110/104891) linked in your question.

After removing the gem you need to ensure it's not referenced anywhere in the project. In this particular case `r_spec_runner.rb` had `require 'ruby-debug'` statement causing `cannot load such file -- ruby-debug` error when trying to run `rails console`.

Comment: I have done. I comment out gem 'debugger', install the two debug gems and then add them to my gemfile and finally bundle update

Comment: Note that since RubyMine 4.5 you can disable `debugger` gem related code like this: `gem "debugger" unless ENV["RM_INFO"]`.

Comment: For those still having problems after following this answer, if you are on Mac OSX make sure your computer name is set in System Preferences | Sharing. It took me forever to figure this out. More detail here: http://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/RUBY-8990

Comment: As soon as I commented out gem 'debugger' in my Gemfile, it started working.

Answer (score 9):

To escape this problem I have this line in my `Gemfile`:
`gem 'debugger' unless ENV["RM_INFO"]`

Comment: AFAIK this won't affect the Gemfile.lock so folks using RubyMine still get borked

Comment: [This should work](http://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/RUBY-11800#comment=27-417333).

Answer (score 6):

Just to document the solution from jetbrains:
Use either:

```
gem 'debugger', {group: [:test, :development]}.merge(ENV['RM_INFO'] ? {require: false} : {})
```

Or:

```
gem 'pry-debug', {group: [:test, :development]}.merge(ENV['RM_INFO'] ? {require: false} : {})
```

This makes sure that the Gemfile.lock remains unchanged, so a group with mixed RubyMine and vi/sublime/whatever can work happily, by do not requiring the gem in a RubyMine environment.

Answer (score 3):

I had the same issue, and it cost me hours to get it working. Here is what finally got the debugger going (this is using RVM):

- Quit RubyMine
- If Ruby 1.9.3 is installed, uninstall it: `rvm remove 1.9.3`
- Install Ruby 1.9.3 under RVM: `rvm install 1.9.3 --with-gcc=clang` - this produces the error "unsupported option '--with-libyaml'", but I haven't seen any ill effects from this yet
- Switch to the new ruby: `rvm use 1.9.3`
- List and remove all ruby-debug* gems:  `gem list | grep debug` - `gem uninstall <found gems>`
- Download linecache19 from http://rubyforge.org/frs/?group_id=8883 and install the gem, i.e.: `gem install linecache19-0.5.13.gem`
- Lauch RubyMine, and run the debugger; it will inform about missing debug gems (i.e. ruby-debug-ide); let RubyMine install those.

That's when the debugger started working. See also this RubyMine support discussion: http://devnet.jetbrains.com/message/5443846#5443846

Comment: Can't seem to download 0.5.13 any more.  Page load times out.  I don't understand how RM is shipping without the debugger working.

Comment: I ran `gem build gem build linecache19-0.5.13.gemspec` after `git clone git@github.com:robmathews/linecache19-0.5.13` Here's the file if you trust me :) https://dl.dropbox.com/u/9632169/linecache19-0.5.13.gem

Comment: I haven't had any issues with RubyMine 5. Seems to work out of the box after it installed the gems it needed.

Answer (score 0):

Finally got this working today with a huge kludge hack. I think the step that did it was

1. `sudo chmod -R 777 ~/.rvm`
2. Let RubyMine do its thing

I also made sure to uninstall every gem I had besides `rake`. I think `reby-debug-ide`, `ruby-debug-base19x`, `linecache19`, `ruby_core_source`, `archive-tar-minitar`, and `columnize` are the important ones. I also uninstalled `rvm` and reinstalled with clang. But I'd try just doing the chmod thing first. I tried changing to 766, but RubyMine didn't like it. So huge kludge hack it is. I now get lots of warnings about `Insecure world` but at least the debugger is working. Pretty sure the next version of RubyMine will not use the old [ruby-debug-base19x](https://rubygems.org/gems/ruby-debug-base19x%2019x), but instead the more recently edited gems at https://github.com/ruby-debug. So hopefully someone at the awesome JetBrains will fix it. Btw also tried running RubyMine with `sudo mine` but that didn't do the trick either.

Answer (score 0):

I had some problems with the debugger.
I installed Rails and set the path in configuration options to the ruby.exe in the rails installation and everything is working perfect.

Comment: More of a comment than an answer. Pls consider making this a comment.