# RubyMine lost debugger after step several line?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rubymine

I'm developing a Rails project using RubyMine 4.5.4.
After few lines of stopping over the code, RubyMine seems lost connect to the debugger.
`Step Into`,`Step over` buttons went disabled and I can not access `localhost:3000`.

Is that a bug of RubyMine or I have to do something to make RubyMine happy?

Update:
I'm using Windows 7 64bit

```
D:\>ruby --version
ruby 1.9.3p392 (2013-02-22) [i386-mingw32]

D:\>gem list --local|grep debug
debugger (1.6.0)
debugger-linecache (1.2.0)
debugger-ruby_core_source (1.2.2)
ruby-debug-base19x (0.11.30.pre12, 0.11.30.pre10)
ruby-debug-ide (0.4.17.beta17, 0.4.17.beta14)
```

Comment: What OS do you use? Do you have the [right debug gems](http://stackoverflow.com/a/10325110/104891) installed? What is the Ruby version?

Comment: @CrazyCoder I update my post. I'm using Win7,Ruby 1.9.3

Comment: `debugger` gem must not be used, see [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/11674999/104891).

Comment: @CrazyCoder, I uninstalled `debugger` gem. `
debugger-ruby_core_source (1.2.2)
ruby-debug-base19x (0.11.30.pre12)
ruby-debug-ide (0.4.17.beta17)`. when I step over some line, there's an HTTP500: @last_breakpoint supposed to be nil. is #<Debugger::Breakpoint:0x2bea308>

Comment: Great. If the issue still remains, please share a sample project to reproduce it.

Comment: @CrazyCoder, I uninstalled debugger yesterday. Today I encounter a new problem: `RuntimeError in ClinicsController#get_reservation_form @last_breakpoint supposed to be nil. is #Debugger::Breakpoint:0x2aaaef8>`  . debug gem: debugger-ruby_core_source (1.2.2)
ruby-debug-base19x (0.11.30.pre12, 0.11.30.pre10)
ruby-debug-ide (0.4.17.beta17, 0.4.17.beta14)

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/30869/discussion-between-aztack-and-crazycoder)