# Connecting to Debugger timeout error in RubyMine

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3.2, rubymine

I have RubyMine 5.4.1

Until yesterday I was successfully able to put a break point in my ruby code, - A Rails app - and from the Run menu say "Debug Development" and it would run in debug mode and I could see my variables, step through my code, awesome. The only reason I got RubMine anyway.

But not sure what happened that I started getting that message box that says connection to debugger in 10 seconds which I even increased it to 30 seconds and still no luck. So after that 10 or 30 seconds time out this is also the error message I get:

[image]

This is also an screen shot of my Debug config if that helps:

[image]

Comment: Have you updated your Ruby version or gems since then? I've found that it's sensitive to different versions of the debugger gem.

Comment: @MattGibson: Nop, I just turned it off after work today....this morning turned it on and not working :( But let's say somehow something has changed regarding these version, then what would the solution be?

Comment: Check [these](http://stackoverflow.com/a/10325110/104891) [answers](http://stackoverflow.com/a/11674999/104891).

Comment: @CrazyCoder: Thanks but those are getting different error messages

Comment: @CrazyCoder : I also updated the question with the error I see in the console window of RubyMine, do you see anything more detail in that?

Comment: Reboot your system, reinstall debug gems.

Comment: @CrazyCoder : Ok thanks will reboot now but what do you mean by "reinstall debug gems" ? Should I just do a bundle install ? or a bundle update or something else?  Thanks for follow up.

Comment: @CrazyCoder : Will it will these two versions? gem install ruby-debug-base19x --pre
gem install ruby-debug-ide --pre

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/31674/discussion-between-ericfromsouthpark-and-crazycoder)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In case of the weird issues possibly caused by networking rebooting the system may help.

Answer (score 0):

In my case, not setting the computer name was the problem. You can use the following code in terminal to set the computer name

```
sudo scutil --set HostName [NewHostNameHere]
```