# RubyMine fails at rails 4, ruby 2.0.0-p0 debugging

Tags: rubymine, ruby-2.0

RubyMine 5.4.2 Ruby 2.0.0-p0 When i try to run debugger it falls out with following. What's wrong with it?

https://gist.github.com/panasyuk/5829345

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Debugger gem [must not be used](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11674999/104891), it conflicts with `ruby-debug-ide` and breaks it.

**UPDATE**: RubyMine 6+ supports debugger gem.

Comment: ruby-debug-ide is the gem you need to use.

Comment: Does rubymine IDE debugger works with ruby 2.0. I cant get it to work with ruby 2.0. It was fine with my 1.9.3. Infact i cant even install ruby-debug-ide, linecache, ruby-debug-base19x etc.

Comment: @AMBasra Ruby 2.0 debugging is fully supported in the current RubyMine version.

Comment: @CrazyCoder. Yes you are right. I figured it out that RubyMine versions 4.x doesnt support Ruby 2.0 debugging so i had to upgrade to 5.x version and now its working fine. Thankyou.

Answer (score 3):

I also had gem 'pry-debugger' enabled, disable that too.

So, just the following, and it works!

```
gem 'ruby-debug-ide'

#not these
#gem 'debugger'
#gem 'pry-debugger'
```