# Running Zeus in Debugger with Rubymine

Tags: rubymine, zeus

[This](http://confluence.jetbrains.com/display/RUBYDEV/Faster+Rails+Development+with+Zeus#FasterRailsDevelopmentwithZeus-4.DebuggingwithZeus) tutorial claims that running zeus in debug mode is as easy as clicking the debug button, however whenever I do I get the following error

```
Fast Debugger (ruby-debug-ide 0.4.22, debase 0.0.8) listens on 127.0.0.1:50192
1663: Exception in DebugThread loop: closed stream
Backtrace:
/Users/InTents/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p247@blinky/gems/ruby-debug-ide-0.4.22/lib/ruby-debug-ide/interface.rb:44:in `close'
from: /Users/InTents/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p247@blinky/gems/ruby-debug-ide-0.4.22/lib/ruby-debug-ide/interface.rb:44:in `close'
from: /Users/InTents/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p247@blinky/gems/ruby-debug-ide-0.4.22/lib/ruby-debug-ide/ide_processor.rb:103:in `ensure in process_commands'
from: /Users/InTents/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p247@blinky/gems/ruby-debug-ide-0.4.22/lib/ruby-debug-ide/ide_processor.rb:103:in `process_commands'
```

from: /Users/InTents/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p247@blinky/gems/ruby-debug-ide-0.4.22/lib/ruby-debug-ide.rb:122:in `block in start_control'

What gives? What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1):

Make sure to remove the `debugger` gem from your gemfile. You can make it conditional on whether RubyMine is running, like this:

```
unless ENV['RM_INFO']
  gem 'debugger'
end
```

See https://stackoverflow.com/a/11674999/278488 for more details.

Answer (score 0):

This looks to be a **[bug](http://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/RUBY-14585)** that was fixed with RubyMine 6.0.1

Comment: I still have this issue. Using Rubymine 6.0.2

Comment: Same here under 6.0.2

Comment: I still have under 6.0.2

Answer (score 0):

If you add the [debugger-xml](http://rubygems.org/gems/debugger-xml) gem, Rubymine will co-exist peacefully with the debugger. I'm running Zeus in the debugger from Rubymine 6.0.3, following the directions in the [Rubymine Manual](http://www.jetbrains.com/ruby/webhelp/executing-tests-on-zeus-server.html). You can then run the server or specs using the regular run command (not the debug run command) and zeus will launch it in the debugger. It's super fast to start up and a joy to use.