# linecache19 with ruby 1.9.3-p194 and rvm

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rubymine, linecache

I've been trying to install `linecache19` following these [instructions](https://gist.github.com/2435951)

```
curl -OL http://rubyforge.org/frs/download.php/75414/linecache19-0.5.13.gem
gem install linecache19-0.5.13.gem -- --with-ruby-include=$rvm_path/src/ruby-1.9.3-p194/
```

I seem to be able to run `curl -OL http://rubyforge.org/frs/download.php/75414/linecache19-0.5.13.gem` just fine, but when I run `gem install linecache19-0.5.13.gem -- --with-ruby-include=$rvm_path/src/ruby-1.9.3-p194/` I get this output:

```
ERROR:  Could not find a valid gem 'linecache19-0.5.13.gem' (>= 0) in any repository
ERROR:  Possible alternatives: linecache193
```

I am running all these commands in the root directory of my rails app.

**EDIT**
I'm using RubyMine, so I think I have to stick with the somewhat older debugging tools

**EDIT 2**
I got this to work by visiting the rubygems page and downloading linecache19 from there, then running `gem install` from the download directory

Comment: I'd recommend ditching ruby-debug and going to the more up-to-date [https://rubygems.org/gems/debugger](debugger) gem. It has the same interface, but is maintained and works with 1.9.3.

Comment: @Beerlington Thanks for the info, question updated (I'm using RubyMine)

Comment: See the full installation log from my system, it may help: http://pastebin.com/qUhrH88U. See also http://stackoverflow.com/a/10325110/104891 for the correct `Gemfile`.

Comment: When are you getting the error? The pastebin shows it installing successfully.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Something was amiss when I tried to `curl` the gem.  When I visited the rubyforge site and downloaded the gem manually, everything worked.