# debugging a sinatra app with rubmine

Tags: ruby, debugging, rubymine

I'm trying to debug a sinatra app using RubyMine. I am using `rackup` to run the app on localhost and `unicorn` to run it on remote host. My ruby version is 1.9.3.

I should also note that the "run debug mode icon" is grayed out. I don't know what is missing from the configuration.

What gems do I need? What else do I need to do?

**update:**
I have run the server process on localhost using `rackup -p 9000`. In order to start debugging -run  `rdebug-ide --port 1234 -- rackup` and got this message :

```
Fast Debugger (ruby-debug-ide 0.4.17.beta16, ruby-debug-base 0.10.5.rc1) listens on 127.0.0.1:1234
```

I still don't understand how to debug using Rubymine. I have opened the browser in `http://0.0.0.0:1234` and I don't get any response (it keeps loading)

I run the remote host using unicorn like so :

```
unicorn -c etc/fin_srv_unicorn.conf -E staging
```

how shold I set up remote debugging? I have tried also `rack` and `ruby remote`. 
Tried connection to the remote host and running the service (using the  command listed above), and then running the rdebug like so :

```
rdebug-ide --port 1911 -- $SCRIPT$
```

where for $SCRIPT$ I have tried `app/main.rb staging` , `unicorn -E staging`, `unicorn -c etc/fin_srv_unicorn.conf -E staging`

Comment: See [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/10325110/104891) for the gems. [Remote debug configuration](http://www.jetbrains.com/ruby/webhelp/remote-debugging.html) can be used.

Comment: hi @CrazyCoder, I should point out that the `run debug mode` icon is grayed out, so I need to solve that first

Comment: Did you read about Remote debug? You start the process outside RubyMine and then connect to it with the debugger.

Comment: I have read it and didn't quite understand what should I do, tried entering `rdebug-ide --port 1234 --dispatcher-port 26162 -- $SCRIPT$` under Run/Debug configuration -> Ruby but the button is still grayed out

Comment: You should start the server process with this command and then use [**Ruby remote debug**](http://img713.imageshack.us/img713/9353/20130209081248.png) configuration type to connect and debug it.

Comment: hi @CrazyCoder, see update in msg body

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/24233/discussion-between-webqube-and-crazycoder)