# How to debug ruby code

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rubymine

I want to debug my Ruby code using the Ruby Mine IDE. In the drop down list `Select Run/Debug Configuration`, I chose `My Project - development`, then pressed `Shift + F9`. The Debugger started well, but did not stop at my break points. Why?

Answer (score 2):

Ensure your Gemfile contains this:

```
gem 'linecache19', '>= 0.5.13', :git => 'https://github.com/robmathews/linecache19 0.5.13.git'
gem 'ruby-debug-base19x', '>= 0.11.30.pre12'
gem 'ruby-debug-ide', '>= 0.4.17.beta17'
```

maybe for details see that [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10323119/cannot-load-such-file-script-rails-getting-this-error-while-remote-debuggin/10325110#10325110)

Comment: Uncaught exception: bad URI(is not URI?): https://github.com/robmathews/linecache19 0.5.13.git

Answer (score 1):

Try using command line debugger: https://github.com/cldwalker/debugger

See also

- http://railscasts.com/episodes/54-debugging-with-ruby-debug
- http://railscasts.com/episodes/54-debugging-ruby-revised

Comment: But, it seems, I have no choose :)

Answer (score 1):

`pry` is an interactive Ruby shell (or "REPL"), which can be used as a debugger (best combined with the `pry-nav` and `pry-stack_explorer` gems). It has a lot of features which make it much nicer to use than the `debugger` gem. For general exploration and experimentation with Ruby code, it's also nicer to use than `irb`.

For more info:

http://pryrepl.org/

https://github.com/pry/pry

After adding `pry` to your Gemfile and bundling, you can add a "breakpoint" with the following  Ruby code: `binding.pry`